# How to make contains() method dynamic in selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I am tring to pass the value from excel to xpath but I am getting noSuchElementFoundException.

This is the code :

```
public String accountBalance(String accountNameToFind)
{
    String accountBalance = null;
    accountBalance = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'" + accountNameToFind + "')]/following-sibling::td")).getText();
    return accountBalance;
}
```

HTML:

```
<tr>
    <th scope="row" class="">
        SDRSP
        <sup>2</sup> - <span class="td-copy-nowrap">1253 3292AUS</span>
        <strong>
            <a href="servlet/ca.tdbank.banking.servlet.SiteTransferOutServlet?dest=BROKER" class="td-link-standalone td-link-standalone-secondary">
                <span class="td-copy-nowrap">
                    WebBroker
                    <span class="td-link-icon">›</span>
                </span>
            </a>
        </strong>
    </th>
    <td class="td-copy-align-right">
        $10,000.00
    </td>
    <td class="td-copy-align-centre">
        &nbsp;
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Show target element's `HTML` sample

Comment: Sorry but I cannot show you the webpage because of company policies.

Comment: Not the full source, but only `HTML` of target element. You can simplify it- remove sensitive data..

Comment: before SDRSP I have

Comment: <tr>
       <th scope="row" class="">

Comment: And what value you want to use to substitute `"+accountNameToFind+"`? `SDRSP `, `1253 3292AUS`...?

Comment: SDRSP or any other random word

Comment: Can you check whether this table located inside an `iframe`?

Comment: yes, it is inside an iframe

Comment: no it is not inside iframe, it is inside frameset-->frame

Comment: When you post a question, please take a few minutes to make sure the HTML and code is properly formatted. Code can be easily formatted by your IDE before pasting. For the HTML there are plenty of HTML formatters online.

Answer (score 1):

If your element located inside `frame`, you need to switch to it first and then handle element:

```
driver.switchTo().frame("frame_ID");
accountBalance=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'"+accountNameToFind+"')]/following-sibling::td")).getText();
...some other actions...
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

If your frame has no `id` attribute you can try to use another attributes, e.g. `class` name:

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("frame.frameClassName")));
```

Comment: Did you get any exceptions?

Answer (score 0):

Your function should be simplified to the below.

```
public String accountBalance(String accountNameToFind)
{
    return driver.findElement(By.xpath("//th[contains(text(),'" + accountNameToFind + "')]/following-sibling::td")).getText();
}
```

I replaced `*` with `th` in the XPath because I'm assuming that the `th` is going to be the only element that you want to use. The accountName may exist elsewhere on the page and be causing issues.

If this is in a frame/iframe, you will need to switch to the frame first as in @Andersson's answer.

This may be a case where this portion of the page is dynamic so you may have to wait for the element to be visible before trying to scrape the data. See `WebDriverWait` with `ExpectedConditions.elementToBeVisible()`.